# Ember 1.12 now requiring me to use mode.propertyName rather than accessing properties directly

Tags: ember.js, properties, upgrade, models

Just upgraded to 1.12, and where I had a project route that returns a single project from the store, previously I could access the properties of that model directly like `{{projectName}}`, but now I have to use `{{model.projectName}}`. can anyone shed light on what's going on?

**Link-to from my projects route:**

`{{#link-to 'project.details' project.id title="Go to project details"}}`

**Model hook in project route:**

```
model: function(params) {
  var record = this.store.getById('project', params.project_id)
  if(record) {
    return record.reload()
  } else {
    return this.store.find('project', params.project_id)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the controller for the projects route yourself?

I'm guessing that maybe you were relying on an `Ember.ObjectController` being generated for you, and that Ember is now generating a regular `Ember.Controller` for you.

If that's the case, you can revert to the old behavior by defining your own controller for the projects route. If you're using ember-cli:

```
// app/controllers/projects.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
```

### However...

`ObjectController`, along with the proxying behavior that you're expecting has been deprecated and is going to be removed in Ember 2.0. I'd recommend using `Ember.Controller` and `model.property` going forward.

You can read more about that at http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller

Comment: That's correct, I didn't define the project route myself, so it was being set automatically. Thanks for the link too; that helps explain it; it just seems odd to me that with all the other reduction of boilerplate, that I now have to add `model.` everywhere.